# Application session maintainance

Tags: java, session, struts2, session-variables, session-timeout

I am working on struts2 web application. Now I need to maintain a session in my application  when the user logs in and then the same session id should be maintained in whole application. Suppose if i open one of my application URL in some different browser then by checking the session it should redirect me to the Login page. How can I proceed.

Comment: One Browser-One URL = One Session. What you are talking about is an scope shared among the users, then an Application scope...

Comment: Is this URL mapped to the action?

Comment: Yes, the url is mapped with the action.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Struts 2 session management is discussed in the docs, but nutshell is to use the `SessionAware` interface.